# How can I center this <div>?

Tags: html, css

Here's what's happening: http://prntscr.com/g67d7p

[image]

As you can see, the "payout box" is not centering correctly. I tried multiple things to fix this but they all failed.

CSS:

```
div[id=rollover-button]{
    height: 100px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

div[id=payout-button]{
    height: 100px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
}

div[id=chance-button]{
    height: 100px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="buttons">
            <div id="rollover-button">
                >50.00
            </div>
            <div id="payout-button">
                2.0000x
            </div>
            <div id="chance-button">
                50%
            </div>
        </div>
```

How can I fix this to make the payout box perfectly centered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This, Simple method to achieve this.

```css
div[id=buttons]{
  margin: 0 auto; 
  text-align: center;
}
div[id=rollover-button]{
    height: 100px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

div[id=payout-button]{
    height: 100px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;        
}

div[id=chance-button]{
    height: 100px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
<div id="rollover-button">
>50.00
</div>
<div id="payout-button">
2.0000x
</div>
<div id="chance-button">
50%
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `flex` property. I have removed all `floats` and `display` properties from elements and used `flex` on the parent. Hope this helps you.

```css
#buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div[id=rollover-button] {
  height: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #E4ECF1;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: 300;
}

div[id=payout-button] {
  height: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #E4ECF1;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: 300;
}

div[id=chance-button] {
  height: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #E4ECF1;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <div id="rollover-button">
    >50.00
  </div>
  <div id="payout-button">
    2.0000x
  </div>
  <div id="chance-button">
    50%
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
 #buttons > div {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

instead of fixed width for each button class div. (This will work with all browsers responsively)

OR if you want some space between boxes then use

```
#buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
#buttons > div {
    width: 33.33%;
}
div[id=rollover-button]{
    height: 100px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

div[id=payout-button]{
    height: 100px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
}

div[id=chance-button]{
    height: 100px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
            <div id="rollover-button">
                >50.00
            </div>
            <div id="payout-button">
                2.0000x
            </div>
            <div id="chance-button">
                50%
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following.

```
div[id=rollover-button]{
    height: 100px;
    width: 33%;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

div[id=payout-button]{
    height: 100px;
    width: 33%;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
}

div[id=chance-button]{
    height: 100px;
    width: 33%;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a flexbox for the container and put space in between the flex items.

```css
#buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div[id=rollover-button] {
  height: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #E4ECF1;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
}

div[id=payout-button] {
  height: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #E4ECF1;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
}

div[id=chance-button] {
  height: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #E4ECF1;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <div id="rollover-button">
    >50.00
  </div>
  <div id="payout-button">
    2.0000x
  </div>
  <div id="chance-button">
    50%
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div[id=buttons]{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div[id=rollover-button]{
    height: 100px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
}

div[id=payout-button]{
    height: 100px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
}

div[id=chance-button]{
    height: 100px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And, I want to say One thing.

I think you can reduce your CSS Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tables that is the easy way.
If you want to use div itself "Go for bootstrap."

That must help.